# custom css for content types in Drupal

Tags: nodes, theming

Basing on existing content type (page) I have created another content type (page-without-video).  The only one difference between these two types, is that I am looking to skip a video section in the second one.  The rest should look the same.  After creating the "page without video" content type, I went ahead and adjusted custom css for the newly created content type (basically just changing the node name from "page" to "page-without-video").   From some reason the new content type did not inherit all the css coding of the "page" and has those default weird lines around images etc.  Is it a css problem or maybe I should look elsewhere to fix it?

I will appreciate any help with this.

Answer (score 2):

Use [Code per Node](https://drupal.org/project/cpn) module, that is the easiest way to add custom CSS or JavaScript on node page, content type or block...

Look at [THIS](https://drupal.org/node/833792) for other ways to add custom css...

Comment: I appreciate your answer.  I will try the module you have suggested. I thought that one more way could be to create a separate template for this page in case this is not a css problem?

Comment: regarding Code per Node, I have a drupal 6.22 version and Code per Node is 6x-1.2 version.  Can I still install it? ( I am a newby...:)

Comment: Sure, you can...in '6.x-1.2' 6.x says that is for Drupal 6 any version and 1.2 is module version...

Answer (score 0):

Are you working from a purchased or existing theme with subtheme? If so code per node isn't the solution, there is just one file you need to copy from the base theme to the subtheme directory and I'm here looking for the name of that file which I have forgotten. Found it Copy node.tpl.php from the theme to the subtheme directory and BAM there are your CSS settings again.